# Access to Jira API in Ruby only by username, password and URL

Tags: ruby, jira, jira-rest-api

I can't login to Jira board by web account, to create Jira API Token. Is there any way to access an API with only username, password and url in Ruby? how to check if this connection is successfully?

Answer (score 1):

What gem are you using? Check out `jira-ruby`, https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby

They just ask for exactly what you have access to, your username and password:

Example usage:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'jira-ruby'

options = {
  :username     => 'username',
  :password     => 'pass1234',
  :site         => 'http://mydomain.atlassian.net:443/',
  :context_path => '',
  :auth_type    => :basic
}

client = JIRA::Client.new(options)

project = client.Project.find('SAMPLEPROJECT')

project.issues.each do |issue|
  puts "#{issue.id} - #{issue.summary}"
end
```

Once logged in you should then have access to all the Jira API commands needed